# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I'm try to make a small online store for my uni coursework and I've stumbled upon this error i don't understand. First off here is the code for my order page.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  

        Dim strSessionID As String
        Dim strItem As String
        Dim strQuantity As String
        strSessionID = Session.SessionID
        strItem = Session("Item")
        strQuantity = Session("Quantity")
        tbxItem.Text = strItem
        tbxQuantity.Text = strQuantity

    End sub

    Protected Sub btnAddOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim strItem As String
        Dim strQuantity As String
        Dim strFullName As String
        Dim strAddressLine As String
        Dim intPhoneNumber As Integer
        Dim intCardNumber As Integer
        Dim strNameOnCard As String
        Dim strExpirationDate As String

        strItem = tbxItem.Text
        strQuantity = tbxQuantity.Text
        strFullName = tbxFullName.Text
        strAddressLine = tbxAddressLine.Text
        intPhoneNumber = tbxPhoneNumber.Text
        intCardNumber = tbxCardNumber.Text
        strNameOnCard = tbxNameOnCard.Text
        strExpirationDate = tbxExpirationDate.Text

        Dim strDatabaseNameAndLocation As String
        strDatabaseNameAndLocation = Server.MapPath("pcland.mdb")
        Dim strSQLCommand As String
        strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO orders(Item, Quantity, FullName, AddressLine, PhoneNumber, CardNumber, NameOnCard, ExpirationDate) " & _
            "Values ('" & strItem & "','" & strQuantity & "','" & strFullName & "', '" & strAddressLine & "', '" & intPhoneNumber & "', '" & intCardNumber & "', '" & strNameOnCard & "', '" & strExpirationDate & "');"
        Dim objOleDbConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)
        objOleDbConnection.Open()
        Dim objOleDbCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        objOleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand, objOleDbConnection)
        objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objOleDbConnection.Close()        
        strSQLCommand = "SELECT orders.* FROM orders ORDER BY orders.Price DESC;"
        objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)       
        tbxItem.Text = ""
        tbxQuantity.Text = ""
        tbxFullName.Text = ""
        tbxAddressLine.Text = ""
        tbxPhoneNumber.Text = ""
        tbxCardNumber.Text = ""
        tbxNameOnCard.Text = ""
        tbxExpirationDate.Text = ""

        lblConfirmationMessage.Text = "Thank you for order."

    End Sub

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>PC land | Cart</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link href="#" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="webform" runat="server">
            <div>
                <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Item:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxItem" ReadOnly="True" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxQuantity" ReadOnly="True" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Full Name:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxFullName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFullName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxFullName" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter your full name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address Line:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxAddressLine" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddressLine" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxAddressLine" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter your address</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxPhoneNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhoneNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxPhoneNumber" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter your phone number (No spaces or dashs)</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Card Number:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxCardNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCardNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxCardNumber" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter the card number (No spaces or dashs)</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Name On Card:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxNameOnCard" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNameOnCard" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxNameOnCard" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter the full name that is on the card </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Expiration Date:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbxExpirationDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvExpirationDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxExpirationDate" 
                    Display="Dynamic">You must enter the expiration date (Example format: 01/02/90)</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Button id="btnAddRecord" runat="server" onclick="btnAddOrder_Click" postbackurl="confirm.aspx" text="Submit" /></td><br />
                </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmationMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2012 PC Land - All Rights Reserved</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now here is the code for the confirm page which should display the choices that the user picked on the order page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim tbxItem As TextBox
        Dim tbxQuantity As TextBox
        Dim tbxFullName As TextBox
        Dim tbxAddressLine As TextBox
        Dim tbxPhoneNumber As TextBox
        Dim tbxCardNumber As TextBox
        Dim tbxNameOnCard As TextBox
        Dim tbxExpirationDate As TextBox

        Dim strItem As String
        Dim strQuantity As String
        Dim strFullName As String
        Dim strAddressLine As String
        Dim intPhoneNumber As Integer
        Dim intCardNumber As Integer
        Dim strNameOnCard As String
        Dim strExpirationDate As String


        tbxItem = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxItem"), TextBox)
        tbxQuantity = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxQuantity"), TextBox)
        tbxFullName = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxFullName"), TextBox)
        tbxAddressLine = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxAddressLine"), TextBox)
        tbxPhoneNumber = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxPhoneNumber"), TextBox)
        tbxCardNumber = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxCardNumber"), TextBox)
        tbxNameOnCard = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxNameOnCard"), TextBox)
        tbxExpirationDate = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbxExpirationDate"), TextBox)

        strItem = tbxItem.Text
        strQuantity = tbxQuantity.Text
        strFullName = tbxFullName.Text
        strAddressLine = tbxAddressLine.Text
        intPhoneNumber = tbxPhoneNumber.Text
        intCardNumber = tbxCardNumber.Text
        strNameOnCard = tbxNameOnCard.Text
        strExpirationDate = tbxExpirationDate.Text

        lblItem.Text = "You said your item was " & strItem
        lblQuantity.Text = "You said your quantity was " & strQuantity
        lblFullName.Text = "You said your full Name was " & strFullName
        lblAddressLine.Text = "You said your Address was " & strAddressLine
        lblPhoneNumber.Text = "You said your item was " & intPhoneNumber
        lblCardNumber.Text = "You said your item was " & intCardNumber
        lblNameOnCard.Text = "You said the name on your card was " & strNameOnCard
        lblExpirationDate.Text = "You said the expiration date was " & strExpirationDate

    End Sub

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>PC land | Cart</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link href="#" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="webform" runat="server">
            <div>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblCardNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblNameOnCard" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblExpirationDate" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2012 PC Land - All Rights Reserved</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

Line 37:         strFullName = tbxFullName.Text
Line 38:         strAddressLine = tbxAddressLine.Text
Line 39:         intPhoneNumber = tbxPhoneNumber.Text
Line 40:         intCardNumber = tbxCardNumber.Text
Line 41:         strNameOnCard = tbxNameOnCard.Text


Source File: D:\SOC Students Web Site\students\insc\insc209\project\confirm.aspx    Line: 39

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +201
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +66

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +246
   ASP.students_insc_insc209_project_confirm_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SOC Students Web Site\students\insc\insc209\project\confirm.aspx:39
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

It's putting the information in the database but obviously I want to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you see this error message:

> Input string was not in a correct format

It is involved in converting data from one type to another, and the conversion was not successful.  Looking at the code, you have declared `intPhoneNumber` as type `Integer`:

```
Dim intPhoneNumber As Integer
```

Since VB.Net provides automatic type coercion, this line is attempting to take the string value of the contents of the phone number textbox and convert it to a number:

```
intPhoneNumber = tbxPhoneNumber.Text
```

What is most likely happening is your phone number was entered in a format like `(123) 456-7890`, which cannot be converted into an Integer.  If you truly want the user to enter a valid number, you want to provide validation and error-checking as defensive coding practices:

```
If IsNumeric(tbxPhoneNumber.Text) Then
    intPhoneNumber = CInt(tbxPhoneNumber.Text)
Else
    MessageBox("Error: Please enter phone as 9-digit number.")
End If
```

**Edit:** I see you have a `RequiredFieldValidator` being applied to the phone number.  That is good, but it will only validate that it was entered.  If you want validation also that it is a 9-digit number, you can use the `RegularExpressionValidator`.  I would recommend making both validators with appropriate error messages to the type of thing they are actually validating, e.g.:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhoneNumber" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="tbxPhoneNumber" 
    Display="Dynamic">
    You must enter your phone number (9 digits, no spaces or dashes)
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator" ID="revPhoneNumber" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="tbxPhoneNumber"
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\d{9}">
    Please enter 9-digit phone number without spaces or dashes
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: The information i entered into the phone number field when testing was just a simple line of number eg 123523. I know there is validation available but I want to solve this issue first before adding anything fancy.

Comment: Try adding the code `CInt(tbxPhoneNumber.Text)` as I show in my example to do the conversion.